# What options for Windows Server 2008/SQL Server 2008 replication/mirroring across data centres?

Tags: windows-server-2008, sql-server-2008, sql, replication, database-mirroring

Our Microsoft web-application processes around 2000 orders per day. I need to support failover to a secondary data centre.

What are the options and experience of implementing a replication/mirroring solution?

I've heard it referred to as geo-replication and I read the MSDN article here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd263442(v=sql.100).aspx which describes the performance.

I'm not a DBA and have limited experience of replication/mirroring. Obviously when the time comes I will bring in the relevent expertise but I would appreciate anyone describing their experience in implementing this.

Answer (score 0):

I have a client who does mirroring (synchronously, but without a witness) from one data-centre to another. Every so often they've had trouble with the link getting flooded, despite no abnormal transactional behaviour. Feels to me like the mirroring is trying to reinitialise, sending more information down the link than it ought to if things were smooth.

I'd generally steer clear of mirroring over large distances, although asynchronous should be better as it doesn't wait for the reply. It then feels a lot like log-shipping without having to wait for the log-backups to be done.